# Font changes inside words

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I want to have intra-word font changes in org mode -- eg. "Teach**er** vs teach**ing**"  -- works fine here in SE markdown. Doesn't in org.

There is this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218238/how-to-make-part-of-a-word-bold-in-org-mode). Is it possible to combine two answers there?
I want to use user81065's use of zero width space along with itsjeyd's suggestion to tweak `org-emphasis-regexp-components`. This is for org mode export *in general.* ie I'd rather avoid latex/html/odt specific methods (as some other answers suggest) and stick to pure org to work with any back-end.

Basically using zero width space shows as an ugly grey blob in odt export.
Can we use the regexp-components to *recognize* the zero width space as a delimiter and then *throw it away?*

Comment: Please clarify the question, to cover what's needed from the other question. It's not clear just what you're doing. Where & when do you want these "font changes" - when doing what?

Comment: I don't know but what's not clear. Anyways added an extra line in 1st & 2nd para

Comment: In `LibreOffice`, disable `Menu Bar -> View -> Field Shadings`.  The "ugly grey blob" will go away.  IOW, you have configured `LIbreOffice` to alert you about the presence of these characters, which are "normally" invisible.

Comment: @whitetrillium One typically uses odt (doc) export to send the document to some vanilla non emacs user. So I don't merely ZWSP to dissappear; it should not be present -- just as org "disappears" stars #+BEGIN_XYZ and much else. IOW the ZWSP is an *org-artifact* not *document-content*

Comment: Hey @whitetrillium Since you understand org export filters Pls take a look at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/73123/5223

Comment: Done.  See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73126/31220

Answer (score 1):

To get this

[image: Intra-word emphasis using Zero Width Space]

export the `org` snippet below after `eval`-ling the setup code.

**(Note that both the setup code and `org` snippet have ZERO WIDTH SPACES and you *CANNOT SEE* these either in this stackexchange post or in your `Emacs` buffer.  *The fontification in `Emacs` buffer  will give you a clue where the ZERO WIDTH SPACE characters are*)**

```
#+options: author:nil broken-links:nil c:nil creator:nil
#+title: Intra-word emphasis using Zero Width Spaces

Teach​*er* vs teach​*ing*

/Method/​-s and =Class=​es

- HiDPI :: *Hi*​gh *D*​ots *P*​er *I*​nch

#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports results
  ;; Tell `whitespace-mode' that we are only interested
  ;; in ZERO WIDTH SPACE chars

  (custom-set-variables
   '(whitespace-display-mappings
     '((space-mark 8203
           [8857])))
   '(whitespace-space-regexp "\\(​+\\)")
   '(whitespace-style
     '(face spaces space-mark)))

  (custom-set-faces
   '(whitespace-space
     ((t
       (:background "yellow" :foreground "firebrick")))))

  ;; Put the `org' buffer in `whitespace-mode', so that we can 
  (whitespace-mode +1)

  ;; Use `C-x r i SPC' to insert ZERO WIDTH SPACE easily
  (set-register ?  "​")

  ;; Remove ZERO WIDTH SPACE from output
  (require 'ox)
  (add-to-list
   'org-export-filter-final-output-functions
   (defun my-org-export-filter-plain-text-functions
       (text backend _info)
     (replace-regexp-in-string "​" "" text t t)))

  ;; Report `org' version
  (format "Demo-ed with `Org-%s'" org-version)
#+end_src
```

---

Here I have extracted the setup `emacs-lisp` code separately

```lisp
;; Tell `whitespace-mode' that we are only interested
;; in ZERO WIDTH SPACE chars
(custom-set-variables
 '(whitespace-display-mappings
   '((space-mark 8203
                 [8857])))
 '(whitespace-space-regexp "\\(​+\\)")
 '(whitespace-style
   '(face spaces space-mark)))

(custom-set-faces
 '(whitespace-space
   ((t
     (:background "yellow" :foreground "firebrick")))))

;; Put the `org' buffer in `whitespace-mode', so that we can 
(whitespace-mode +1)

;; Use `C-x r i SPC' to insert ZERO WIDTH SPACE easily
(set-register ?  "​")

;; Remove ZERO WIDTH SPACE from output
(require 'ox)
(add-to-list
 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions
 (defun my-org-export-filter-plain-text-functions
     (text backend _info)
   (replace-regexp-in-string "​" "" text t t)))

;; Report `org' version
(format "Demo-ed with `Org-%s'" org-version)
```

Comment: I guess the last 8-10 lines is what I'm looking for. The rest as I mentioned (other comment) is potentially useful but not quite my use case. I need to get onto a machine and try (bit later)

Comment: The last `require...` and `add-to-list...` seem to have worked -- Thanks!
For now +1. [I only eval-ed that much]
If you make that the main part of the answer (and the rest as auxiliary for those who may want) I'll accept as well. Thanks again!

Comment: [Intra-word Emphasis in Org mode using ZERO WIDTH SPACEs; East Asian Language Users please take note](https://emacsnotes.wordpress.com/2022/09/09/intra-word-emphasis-in-org-mode-using-zero-width-spaces-east-asian-language-users-please-take-note/)

Comment: This may be worth a separate answer.  But right now various links are broken including the download one.

Comment: Fixed the links.  Filter functions in that library are "better" ones than the ones suggestion here.