# Leading * breaks code

Tags: org-mode, python

I don't know if the presence of a leading * was meant to be in the code or if it's just a typo, but still I didn't expect it would break the code as if interpreted as a headline. Has dis been documented somewhere?

```
** DONE Programming - Python
  [2022-06-26 Sun]
 
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

Selection    Path                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.8          2         auto mode
1            /usr/bin/python3.8          2         manual mode
2            /usr/local/bin/python3.10   1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
#+END_SRC
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah it breaks... Not sure its intended/bug/... But I got it working by inserting a zero width space before the '*' ie Do `C-x 8 RET ZERO WIDTH SPACE` with point at *, which may cause other problems correctable by part of an answer to my recent question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/72520/5223 -- See my comments

Comment: ANother simpler option is just  indent the whole src block with a space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more idiomatic way to represent a combination of shell code and the output of that code in `orgmode` is to do something like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results verbatim
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).
: 
: Selection    Path                       Priority   Status
: ------------------------------------------------------------
: * 0            /usr/bin/python3.8          2         auto mode
: 1            /usr/bin/python3.8          2         manual mode
: 2            /usr/local/bin/python3.10   1         manual mode
: 
: Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

With this formatting, you can execute the code block to automatically generate the output. Or, if you prefer to manually enter the output, you can just prefix each line with the `:` symbol, and omit the `#+RESULTS:` header.

Comment: "you can execute the code block to automatically generate the output." How so?

Comment: With point in the source block, `C-c C-c`. There may be some configuration needed: https://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-Code-Blocks.html#Evaluating-Code-Blocks

Answer (score 1):

The  best way to create a block, is

1. `C-c C-,`, choose `s` (or whatever) and choose `bash` (or whatever)
2. It will create en empty block like so.

```
#+begin_src sh
#+end_src
```

3. Put your cursor within that block and do `C-c '`. In the resulting buffer, copy the code, indent if needed, and press `C-c C-c`.
4. You will get a block like this

```
#+begin_src sh
$ sudo update-alternatives --config python3
There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

Selection    Path                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
,* 0            /usr/bin/python3.8          2         auto mode
1            /usr/bin/python3.8          2         manual mode
2            /usr/local/bin/python3.10   1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
#+end_src
```

Note the `,` before `*`.  Indenting the block wouldn't work because `org` will think that the `*` is a bullet point.

---

Btw, what you have within your `sh` block is not all shell script.  It is a combination of shell command, its output, and all manner of things. So, use some other block.

Comment: What is the long form of `C-c '`? For me, undefined.

Comment: Are you doing it from an Org mode buffer? It should be bound to `org-edit-special`.