# A one-line org code block

Tags: org-export, latex

I want to have python snippets in org thus:

```
#+begin_PYT
def foo(x):
# Some python code
#+end_PYT
```

where `PYT` is a latex environment for python code using (say) listings.

The problem is that while org does translate `#+begin_PYT` to `\begin{PYT}` it modifies (transcodes??) the body; so for example
the python `[[a]]` becomes an org link a!

As a result using vanilla org I have to do

```
#+begin_export latex
\begin{PYT}
def foo(x):
# Some python code
\end{PYT}
#+end_export
```

With dozens of small snippets those two extra lines are quite an overhead

So options (I can think of!)

1. There should be a way in vanilla org to tell org that a `PYT` block should be left alone (not transcoded)
   Or
2. Using [org-special-blocks-extra](https://github.com/alhassy/org-special-block-extras/) there should be a way but there is very scant documentation.
3. Write a 'pre-transcode' filter that transforms `#+begin_PYT` to `"#+begin_export latex\n\\begin{PYT}"`

Can someone help out with any of these (or some other!) way to do this?

Comment: Why not have a python source block with the code exported? `#+begin_src python :exports code ... #+end_src` - that will use either `listings` or `minted` depending on the setting of `org-latex-listings`.

Comment: @NickD Does this work for non standard languages that org doesn't know about? PYT was just an example.  More realistically I need a mix of python and a homegrown language for which a detailed listings parameterization has been created

Comment: I imagine not, since it does not work with PYT.

Comment: You could also achieve it, using [example blocks with the '#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment pyt' attribute](https://orgmode.org/manual/Example-blocks-in-LaTeX-export.html). Then you need only one extra line. Of course, you could create a snippet for creating such blocks. Note that you might [have to escape some characters](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html). Despite this option, it would probably still be nice(r) to achieve this via a special block and some configuration variable.

Comment: `org-special-blocks-extra` does not provide an out-of-the-box solution to make the `[[a]]` syntax not become org-links (otherwise, the, I would say, [not so scant documentation of org-special-block-extras](https://alhassy.github.io/org-special-block-extras/) does explain, how to achieve what you want.

Comment: @dalanicolai there is o-thread-blockall -- basically block function compose. We need to use that to compose org-export-latex-block with "begin{PYT}"s implied block

Comment: Ah well, that could be, although it might be easier to invent a solution yourself, than to understand that documentation ;) For example, it shows how to use a 'details' block, but not how to use an 'example' block. Anyway, even if we could figure out that documentation, I am still not sure if it will solve the 'link' problem (although it could be of course). I guess for now we're stuck with adding that single extra attribute line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your query is in the docstring of [`org-latex-custom-lang-environments`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/org/ox-latex.el?h=8b31c18fc8669e3b6e493769c7e033ddea08375c#n1082).

Specifically, you want your `ox-latex` setup in such a way that when the exporter hits [`org-latex-src-block`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/org/ox-latex.el?h=8b31c18fc8669e3b6e493769c7e033ddea08375c#n2977), the code takes [this path](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/org/ox-latex.el?h=8b31c18fc8669e3b6e493769c7e033ddea08375c#n3012).

1. Create `somefile.org` with following contents

```
#+begin_src PYT
  def foo(x):
  # Some python code
#+end_src
```

2. `emacs -Q`
3. Copy the following snippet to `*scratch*` and do `M-x eval-buffer`

```lisp
(define-derived-mode PYT-mode prog-mode "PYT"
  "Major mode for PYT files.")

(custom-set-variables
  '(org-latex-custom-lang-environments '((PYT "PYT")))
  '(org-latex-listings 'minted))
```

4. `C-x C-f somefile.org`, followed with `C-c C-e C-b l L` will give you this

```tex
\begin{PYT}
def foo(x):
# Some python code
\end{PYT}
```

Comment: Tnx upvoted. I may need to change minted to listings I guess. Then it (should) work (on phone now)

Comment: I just did `(setq org-latex-custom-lang-environments '((PYT "PYT")))`
and it worked but things inside `[[...]]` looked funny *inside emacs* (latex result ok). Adding 
`(define-derived-mode PYT-mode prog-mode "PYT"
  "Major mode for PYT files.")` and inside emacs is also fine. Why is the minted (or listings) needed?? Anyhow accepted

Comment: O I see whats happening. Without the `(setq org-latex-listings 'listings)` org emits a `\begin{verbatim}`. With it, org properly makes it `\begin{PYT}`